# InstallShield XML File Changes - Change iis port on install

Tags: xml, iis, web-config, installshield, installshield-2015

I am building a web application installation using InstallShield 2015, and I need to modify the Web.config file of my app based on user input. The user can insert the port that will be used in the IIS later on. how can I change the web.config file depending on the insertion of the user ?

[image]

Here is the location of insertion the ports.

[image]

how can I replace any IP inserted by the user during the installation in the xml file "Web.config"?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `loginUrl` should looks like ...

```
http://localhost:[IISSSOPORT]/User/Login
```

Comment: @BishoyEzzat What didn't work? What did you get in the place of the global variable?